# A trigonometry equation

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve this trigonometric equation:

$\sin 84^\circ \sin 18^\circ \sin x = \sin 12^\circ \sin 48^\circ \sin (18^\circ -x)$

I used calculator to get an answer $x=6$ but I don't know how to solve it.
Please help.
Thanks!
Best Regards, Michael

Comment: The two equations are similar but the values are not the same.

Comment: You should be able to use the same method, just substituting in different numbers

Comment: There is a cancellation of factors in the that  equation but there is no cancellation this time and the simplification is not so simple.